# How to estimate the probability of the periodicity of a time series signal

Tags: function, math, probability, periodic-processing, periodicity

I am trying to formulate a function to estimate the probability of a given 1-D vector which is a periodic signal.

For instance, a sine or a cosine wave could result in a probability of 1; a white noise signal should result in a probability close to 0.

Can anyone help me to come up with this function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you call the probability of a signal ?

Comment: See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169805/quantification-of-the-extent-of-periodicity-in-a-time-series-using-fractal-analy).

Comment: @sascha Thank you so much, and the link helps me a lot. It seems that the problem has been solved. Please also move your answer below so that let me tick your response as the answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have changed the title of this question. Please let me know if it is still inappropriate.